# Angular display all reviews inside of a CONST

Tags: javascript, angular, constants

I'm trying to make it so that all the comments inside of the const DISH get displayed. The problem is I have no idea how to display when the comments are embedded inside the const DISH. I've been trying for a while now but no idea.

[like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hERjz.png)
*I already have the left side with the picture just trying to get the reviews to display

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';


const DISH = {
  id: '0',
  name: 'Uthappizza',
  image: '/assets/images/uthappizza.png',
  category: 'mains',
  featured: true,
  label: 'Hot',
  price: '4.99',
  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
  comments: [
       {
           rating: 5,
           comment: 'Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!',
           author: 'John Lemon',
           date: '2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z'
       },
       {
           rating: 4,
           comment: 'Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!',
           author: 'Paul McVites',
           date: '2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z'
       },
       {
           rating: 3,
           comment: 'Eat it, just eat it!',
           author: 'Michael Jaikishan',
           date: '2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z'
       },
       {
           rating: 4,
           comment: 'Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!',
           author: 'Ringo Starry',
           date: '2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
       },
       {
           rating: 2,
           comment: 'It\'s your birthday, we\'re gonna party!',
           author: '25 Cent',
           date: '2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z'
       }
   ]
};


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dishdetail',
  templateUrl: './dishdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dishdetail.component.scss']
})
export class DishdetailComponent implements OnInit {
  

  dishdetail = DISH;
  review = DISH.comments;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container"
    fxLayout="row"
    fxLayout.sm="column"
    fxLayout.xs="column"
    fxLayoutAlign.gt-md="space-around center"
    fxLayoutGap="10px" 
    fxLayoutGap.xs="0">

  <div fxFlex="40">
    <div fxFlex *ngIf="dishdetail">
        <mat-card>
            <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>
                <h3>{{dishdetail.name | uppercase}}</h3>
            </mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <img mat-card-image src= {{dishdetail.image}}>
            <mat-card-content>
                    <p>{{dishdetail.description}}
                    </p>
                  </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div  fxFlex="40">
    <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="200px">
        <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let comments of DISH">
                <mat-grid-tile-footer>
                    <p> {{review.comment}} </p>
                    <p>-- {{review.author}} </p>
                </mat-grid-tile-footer>
        </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! I think you need to change the `*ngFor` to `*ngFor="let comment of DISH.comments"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, change below ngFor for review

```
 <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let review of reviews">
                <mat-grid-tile-footer>
                    <p> {{review.comment}} </p>
                    <p>-- {{review.author}} </p>
                </mat-grid-tile-footer>
        </mat-grid-tile>
```

**In component.ts:**

```
 reviews = this.DISH.comments;
```

working code for reference - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rppl1x?file=src/app/app.component.html

**Issue:** Due to invalid variable **review** from your code, `review.comments` and `review.author` values are undefined, change your component.html and component as mentioned in above example to make work correctly